# Do you synchronize your build script with IDE?

Tags: ide, continuous-integration, build-script

If you used the following:

1. Continuous Integration using build scripts
2. IDE for code development

Do you run into problems of synchronizing your build scripts with the IDE build system? If so, how do you resolve this kind of issue? Using any environment (Java/.NET/etc) to explain the solution will do. I just want to get ideas on how people solve this problem.

Comment: Looks like at least one CI server supports this: http://www.openmakesoftware.com/continuous-integration/

Answer (score 1):

In Java world you can have 2 kind of scripts - build scripts & scripts to generate project file for your favorite IDE (ipr for IDEA for example). Such that if you project's structure have changed just re-run the script that will update .ipr file, for example. Also, various people in the team can work with different IDEs.

In .NET world there are 2 options:

- if you build with MSBuild then you don't need to synchronize anything -    .csproj files from VS are valid MSBuild files as well.
- if you build with NAnt you can run `devenv` task that will go to .sln file and still call .csproj files that are always up to date.

Comment: "...various people in the team can work with different IDEs." Yeah, exactly right, that's what my team is doing.

Comment: Btw, do you have to roll your own scripts to generate the project file? Or the build scripts (e.g. Ant) have plugins for different IDEs?

Comment: We use maven's plugins for this to generate project files just calling *mvn idea:idea* or *mvn eclipse:eclipse*.

There is a link to maven's plugin for idea, for example: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/usage.html